# on_ac_power returns wrong result at laptop start up

Tags: 18.04

On start up, `on_ac_power` on my system always return 1 instead of 0 (even though AC adapter is plugged in). If I unplug then plug the adapter, it will return 0 correctly.

Is there a way to force `on_ac_power` to "recheck" the AC status at system start up instead of having to unplug-plug the adapter?

My system's info:

- Kernel: 4.18.0-17-generic
- Laptop: MacBook Air 2015

Comment: It is a command, not a shell variable. Its exit code determine whether the system is on ac power or not. 0 is true, 1 is false.

Comment: I'm on kernel `4.14.110` and my Dell AW17R3 laptop has been plugged in for the last 100 boots or more. When typing: `if on_ac_power ; then echo YES ; fi` the response is `YES`. Maybe it's not the software but rather the hardware or your configuration?

Comment: I know that this problem is unique to my system. That's why I ask for a way to "force refresh" it. Battery indicator in my desktop always shows the ac status correctly.